# How can a separate search string using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

For a search string like ""foo and bar" or foo", i want to separate string in : 1)"foo and bar" 2)or 3)foo. That means I want to consider the quoted words in a single string. In server side i'm using (Java):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(searchText);
        while (m.find()) {
            String searchTermStr = m.group(1);
            list.add(buildSearchTerm(searchTermStr));
}
```

How can a get similiar output in javascript? I'm trying to split the searchText using this regEx and it's not giving the desired result.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*","gi");
var searchTerms = $scope.searchText.split(pattern);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript you can use this:

```
var pattern = /([^"\s]+|"[^"]*")/g;
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ3nO6/1)

You must use `String#match` in Javascript instead of `split`:

```
var searchTerms = $scope.searchText.match(pattern);
//=> ["foo and bar", or, foo]
```